# Header files missing

Tags: compiling, gcc, make

I'm trying to compile a source code and I'm getting many errors indicating that header files are missing from my system

```
checking sys/ioccom.h usability... no
checking sys/ioccom.h presence... no
checking for sys/ioccom.h... no
checking sys/sockio.h usability... no
checking sys/sockio.h presence... no
checking for sys/sockio.h... no
checking for net/pfvar.h... no
checking for linux/wireless.h... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h usability... no
checking bluetooth/bluetooth.h presence... no
checking for bluetooth/bluetooth.h... no
```

So, I'm starting to think I'm missing some important packages

Can you list them for me?

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 2.6.28-17 kernel and gcc version 4.6.3 and I'm trying to compile this package http://nrg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mptcp/mptcp_userland_0.1.tar.gz

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Hosam, I think you are missing some "important" packages instead of "impotent", or else this must be the wrong site :)

Comment: An auto-corrected typo :D

Comment: But you did not say what are you configuring…

Comment: Added a link to the source files (Y)

Comment: These appear to be kernel headers (`include/net/bluetooth/bluetooth.h`, et al), but you say you are using kernel *2.6.28-17* - which does not match Ubuntu 12.04 (which used 3.2.0, or newer if you installed a HWE stack) - so if you've installed your own kernel, you probably need to ensure for yourself you have the right headers available.

Comment: I installed the old kernel and its corresponding header files from Ubuntu repository, so, I assume they contain all the necessary files

Comment: Could you run this `dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r)`

Comment: I actually installed the headers using apt-get; I modified the "sources.list" file and added Jaunty repositories to be able to install the old kernel/headers version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `find / -iname 'wireless.h'` for example, and found that most of the header files are there but the compiler didn't find them

So, I copied them to `/usr/include/` directory and it worked fine

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Instead of copying the file over, you must add an additional compiler flag: `-I /path/to/net` (the path that includes `bluetooth`). For autoconf, run `./configure --help` to find out environment variables or options that you can use to specify the include directory for bluetooth.

Answer (score 1):

## Missing Headers and Libs

If you haven't installed the libs on your computer, here are the libs on an Ubuntu system:

1. **ioccom.h**

   - lib: freebsd-glue
2. **pfvar.h**

   - lib: linux-headers-generic
3. **wireless.h** and **sockios.h**

   - lib: linux-libc-dev
4. **bluetooth.h**

   - lib: libbluetooth-dev

To install the packages:

```
sudo apt-get install freebsd-glue libbluetooth-dev linux-headers-generic linux-libc-dev
```

Answer (score 0):

## Use the locate command

For instance if you like to find the *ioccom.h* header on your system use:

```
locate -b '\ioccom.h'
```

search in your database for this filename. So you get the paths and so on, assumming these headers are on your machine.

Maybe you have additional to update your database before:

```
sudo updatedb
```

That's the way I'm searching my headers location. It's much faster than using the find command.