# Where does the command make search for libraries

Tags: compiling, libraries, make

I wonder if you can tell me the path `make` command uses to search for libraries and header files, I'm getting [these errors posted in my question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/433118/header-files-missing) and I wanna check the path manually.

I have Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, 2.6.38-16 kernel and gcc version 4.6.3 and I'm trying to compile this package:

http://nrg.cs.ucl.ac.uk/mptcp/mptcp_userland_0.1.tar.gz

Thank you.

Comment: `make` usually searches the working directory for a file called `makefile` and executes it. Check inside there for clues and update your post with the contents if you're still not sure :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `make` command itself does not search for libraries or header files - instead it looks for a Makefile in the current directory (unless an alternative file is specified on the command line using the `-f` option) and executes the instructions inside. Those are usually instructions to specific compilers such as `gcc` and/or `g++`.

The Makefile may add search paths for specific compilation commands using `-I` (for include files) and/or `-L` (for libraries) directives. You can find the *default* search paths in your compiler documentation e.g. [GNU gcc: Search Paths](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) or you can list them directly by processing an empty file with compiler verbosity turned up e.g. [to see what the gcc include path is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939930/finding-out-what-the-gcc-include-path-is)

```
echo | `gcc -print-prog-name=cc1` -v
```

or to see both include and library path information `echo | gcc -xc -E -v -` (for C) or `echo | gcc -xc++ -E -v -` (for C++).

However the question you linked to looks like the output from a `./configure` script rather than from a `make` command. A `./configure` script is part of the GNU automake system and is used to create a 'custom' Makefile for the local build environment by figuring out where various components are located on *your* system. If you have libraries located in non-standard locations, such as other build dependencies that you have also built from source, and installed somewhere like `/usr/local/`, then it may be necessary to pass those locations to the `./configure` script e.g.

```
./configure --with-foo=/usr/local --with-bar=/opt/bar_3.14
```

For specific instructions you will need to refer to the README or similar documentation for the package you are trying to build.

Comment: Thank you for the informative answer. I listed the default search paths using your command and copied a ioccom.h file to one of the paths and that didn't work.

Comment: After that I looked at the MakeFile and the Rules.mk (the make file asks to include Rules.mk). I found this line "INCLUDES        = -I. -I$(TOP)/src/sysinclude -I$(LINUXROOT)/include  \
  -I$(PCAP) -I$(CAP) -I$(PCAP)/bpf -I$(PCAP)/lbl" I copied the header file to (TOP)/src/sysinclude and that didn't work...still getting `checking sys/ioccom.h presence... no`

Comment: I don't mind adding the missing files manually if there is a way or modifing the `./configure` script to include them but I couldn't find it..I only issue the `make` command and I think it runs `./configure` automatically